# Cleaner pandas apply with function that cannot use pandas.Series and non-unique index

Tags: numpy, pandas

In the following, `func` represents a function that uses multiple columns (with coupling across the group) and cannot operate directly on `pandas.Series`.  The `0*d['x']` syntax was the lightest I could think of to force the conversion, but I think it's awkward.

Additionally, the resulting `pandas.Series` (`s`) still includes the group index, which must be removed before adding as a column to the `pandas.DataFrame`.  The `s.reset_index(...)` index manipulation seems fragile and error-prone, so I'm curious if it can be avoided.  Is there an idiom for doing this?

```
import pandas
import numpy

df = pandas.DataFrame(dict(i=[1]*8,j=[1]*4+[2]*4,x=list(range(4))*2))
df['y'] = numpy.sin(df['x']) + 1000*df['j']
df = df.set_index(['i','j'])
print('# df\n', df)

def func(d):
    x = numpy.array(d['x'])
    y = numpy.array(d['y'])
    # I want to do math with x,y that cannot be applied to
    # pandas.Series, so explicitly convert to numpy arrays.
    #
    # We have to return an appropriately-indexed pandas.Series
    # in order for it to be admissible as a column in the
    # pandas.DataFrame.  Instead of simply "return x + y", we
    # have to make the conversion.
    return 0*d['x'] + x + y

s = df.groupby(df.index).apply(func)

# The Series is still adorned with the (unnamed) group index,
# which will prevent adding as a column of df due to
# Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
s = s.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print('# s\n', s)

df['z'] = s
print('# df\n', df)
```

Comment: you don't need to convert the arrays, they already exist in the DataFrame in the class member `values`: `x= d['x'].values` etc.

Comment: Thanks.  That saves a copy, but doesn't change the semantics of using the result.  I thought the example would be more accessible by referencing `numpy.array` explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
0*d['x'] + x + y
```

you could use

```
pd.Series(x+y, index=d.index)
```

---

When using `groupy-apply`, instead of dropping the group key index using:

```
s = df.groupby(df.index).apply(func)
s = s.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
df['z'] = s
```

you can tell `groupby` to drop the keys using [the keyword parameter `group_keys=False`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby):

```
df['z'] = df.groupby(df.index, group_keys=False).apply(func)
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(i=[1]*8,j=[1]*4+[2]*4,x=list(range(4))*2))
df['y'] = np.sin(df['x']) + 1000*df['j']
df = df.set_index(['i','j'])

def func(d):
    x = np.array(d['x'])
    y = np.array(d['y'])
    return pd.Series(x+y, index=d.index)

df['z'] = df.groupby(df.index, group_keys=False).apply(func)
print(df)
```

yields

```
     x            y            z
i j                             
1 1  0  1000.000000  1000.000000
  1  1  1000.841471  1001.841471
  1  2  1000.909297  1002.909297
  1  3  1000.141120  1003.141120
  2  0  2000.000000  2000.000000
  2  1  2000.841471  2001.841471
  2  2  2000.909297  2002.909297
  2  3  2000.141120  2003.141120
```